# How to properly plan and size for a SQL Server Reporting Server database

Tags: database, reporting-services, specifications, sql-server-2017, ssrs-2017

I am trying to understand how to properly plan and size for a SQL Server Report Server database.  As a high level description, my environments will contain a production database, a reporting database (separate database that is a subscriber to the production database) and the SSRS ReportServer and TempDB.

I have a fairly good understanding of my production and reporting server database requirements.  I have been asked to provide requirements for the SSRS ReportServer database.  I have been unable to find information about this on MSDN or and other sites. Can someone provide a link or suggestion for reading material?

Thanks!

Mark

I have searched all over the MSDN and Visual Studio subscriber site.

Comment: I don't have a great answer for you (sorry!) but I will say that in my experience it is much better to over-estimate than to under.

Comment: Better to have and not need than need and not have...

Comment: At our shop, we have 2 reporting servers (SSRS 2012 and 2016). We recently migrated all of our reports over to 2016. SSRS is installed on the reporting server instances. We have over 400 reports and 100 subscriptions. The 2016 SSRS db, is approximately 500Mb total. Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: @WEI_DBA Do you cache any of your reports and if so, how big are they.  I've read that is where the Reporting DB could grow.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: We do. 2 reports are cached due to length of time to run, but they aren't overly huge, so under 1Mb stored each. Sorry couldn't be of much more help.

Comment: @WEI_DBA - Thank you for your quick response.  This is good information and as I suspected.Don't really have to worry about disk space requirements, just i/o speed.